# Quadratic Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to find the integral solutions of
$$
\ x^2 + y^2 =2z^2 
$$
such that x,y are distinct and $$
z^2 < 2(min(x,y))^2 
$$

This can be reduced to $$ a^2 + b^2 = 2 $$ such that a,b are rational numbers.

Comment: See [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/primitive-pyth-triples-solutions-of-x-2-y-2-2-z-2.390717/).

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1051335_pythagorean_triple